# Moving a view using Transition framework

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions, fragment-transitions

I'm trying to create an animation similar to translateX/translateY using Transition framework in xml.
While navigating from fragment A to B, B has some views which needs to be moved from a different position (within the screen bounds) than the final position. I tried to achieve this using `<patternPathMotion>` but it won't accept `<targets>`. Also `Slide` could only animate an object from outside the screen. Also could you direct me to some tutorials or sample code which uses the subclasses of `android.transition` (ChangeBounds, ChangeTransform, ...); Because all the articles talk only about `SharedElementTransition` :-(